# Handling files in Windows like on the Mac

Tags: windows, macos, default, file-handling

It can this is a silly question, but is it possible to handle files on Windows (XP, Vista or 7) like on the Mac?
I clarify: on the Mac you can rename or move a file even if it is currently used by an application, on Windows you simply cannot! There is a way to change this behavior with some black magic on the Registry?

Comment: Your solution is to buy a Mac

Comment: I already use a Mac and Windows that's why I asked  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested You can read about File locking and specific implementations in Windows and Mac here 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking

I use unlocker to get around this problem in Windows. It's quite handy
http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no builtin solution to your problem and I haven't heard of any tool accomplishing that.
It's not possible because the file handling is done in a different way, which is also strongly influenced by the features of the different filesystems.